VS2022 will not build or rebuild project, error MSB4025
When I build or rebuild my project, I simply get a message saying that the build or rebuild has failed.
If I use Tools/Command Line and Developer Command Line or Developer PowerShell and run MSBUILD /v:d I get the final message that it has been successful.
The error MSB4025 seems to relate the .vdproj file, implying that it is not XML.
I am using VS2022 Version 17.11.5.
When I run the compiler normally on other projects i.e. Without the MSB4025 error, I obtain a SETUP.EXE file and a project .MSI file.
How can I either get past this seeming problem with the .vdproj file (My XML knowledge is sparse) or get MSBUILD to produce them?
I am not using Azure or ASP, so I cannot see how the suggested 'Duplicate' answer is relevant.  Also, please see my latest comments.
Update 1: This is an old project, originally in VS2010, that I am having to resuscitate. I have realised that it is probably not the .vdproj file that has the problem. I saw a very similar problem to this, so I have run MSBUILD with the parameters /v:diag /filelogger /p:"Targets=Rebuild" (The /p: parameter was a suggestion in a solution to the similar problem). Once again, MSBUILD says that it has been successful and indeed, EXE files were created in the bin and obj folders, but I still cannot get VS2022 to produce me a Setup.EXE or msi file.
Update 2:
This is the contents of the MSBUILD.LOG file:
-Build started 08/11/2024 08:43:11. Project "C:\Customers\Addey\AddeySon\AddeySetup\AddeySetup.vdproj" on node 1 (default targets). Building with tools version "4.0". C:\Customers\Addey\AddeySon\AddeySetup\AddeySetup.vdproj(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. Done Building Project "C:\Customers\Addey\AddeySon\AddeySetup\AddeySetup.vdproj" (default targets) -- FAILED. Deferred Messages Detailed Build Summary ====================== ============================== Build Hierarchy (IDs represent configurations) ===================================================== Id : Exclusive Time Total Time Path (Targets) ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0 : 0.063s 0.063s C:\Customers\Addey\AddeySon\AddeySetup\AddeySetup.vdproj () Utilization: 100.0 Average Utilization: 100.0 Build FAILED. "C:\Customers\Addey\AddeySon\AddeySetup\AddeySetup.vdproj" (default target) (1) -> C:\Customers\Addey\AddeySon\AddeySetup\AddeySetup.vdproj(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. 0 Warning(s) 1 Error(s) Time Elapsed 00:00:00.15 (I have removed the lines regarding times) "DeployProject" { "VSVersion" = "3:800" "ProjectType" = "8:{978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA}" "IsWebType" = "8:FALSE" "ProjectName" = "8:AddeySetup" "LanguageId" = "3:1033" "CodePage" = "3:1252" "UILanguageId" = "3:1033" "SccProjectName" = "8:" "SccLocalPath" = "8:" "SccAuxPath" = "8:" "SccProvider" = "8:" "Hierarchy" { These are the first few lines of the .vdproj file.

The MS Visual Studio Installer Projects is already installed. Looking at the .vdproj file, and the  length of it, is there any way to completely regenerate it from scratch?

Solved!  The answer was to make the Target Platform x64 instead of x86!  It was an old project and I was trying to get a fresh package to install using the later compiler, and the error shown above did not point me to the Target Platform.

Here is the step-by-step debugging and solution to correct MSB4025 errors in your .vdproj file.
Step 1: Verify .vdproj Compatibility with VS2022

.vdproj (Setup and Deployment Project) is not fully included in Visual Studio 2022 without installing a package.
Install extension Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects
Go to Extensions > Manage Extensions in Visual Studio.


"Find "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" and install.
Reset Visual Studio to take the extension effect.

Step 2: Validate the .vdproj file

Open this .vdproj file with a text editor, such as Notepad.
Verify that it has a valid syntax in it.
Typical errors happen with:
There are either extra blank characters or wrong material in the beginning of the file.
Broken or missing parts. Validate the file hierarchy is correct and consistent with most other .vdproj files.

Step 3: Rebuild Project in Visual Studio
Open solution in Visual Studio 2022
Then right click on solution and choose Rebuild.
Check if .vdproj error persists, that is if the problem is resolved then Visual Studio should build the Setup.exe and .msi files into the output directory.
Run MSBuild with Diagnostic Logging (if the error still occurs)

Open the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio.
Navigate to the project directory.
This command will run a rebuild of the project with extra logging enabled:
MSBUILD /v:diag /filelogger /p:Targets=Rebuild




Open msbuild.log and scan for lines containing error MSB4025 or other errors
. If the log shows a line in .vdproj that contains invalid data, edit the file and resolve structural issues

Step 6: Check Setup Output Files
If the build was successful, in the bin or obj directory, you should find your desired Setup.exe and .msi files
. You should be able to run the installer.
For example, in case the issues persist further, migrate your setup to a supported format such as WiX Toolset or InstallShield, since .vdproj files tend to be tricky to deal with using newer versions of Visual Studio.

answer sponsored by ChatGPT ?
